# how to check whether a string contains words specified in a set

Tags: apex

how to check whether a string contains any element specified in a set of elements?
say for eg:
how to check whether below statement
'I got two dogs and a cat'

contains words specified in set {dog,cat,parrot}

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` class, constructing the regexp pattern from the values of the set, or you could loop through each value in the set and compare it to a value. Solutions are ordered from most flexible to least flexible.

## Pattern and Matcher

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.join(new List<String>(keyWords),'|'));
Matcher m = p.matcher(targetString);
if(m.find()) { ... }
```

- Can be modified to match whole words only, can be made case insensitive, and isn't affected by punctuation.

## Search and Compare

```
Boolean matches = false;
for(String key:keyWords) {
    if(targetString.indexOf(key)>-1) {
        matches = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

- Matches any part of any word; matching whole words would be rather difficult without a complex condition statement.

Comment: I think a `set` has not a method called `containsAny`, but a `string`. And `containsAny` checks for any character and not for the word.

Comment: You can not use String.join with a Set sorry ^^

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that. You can, however, convert a set to a string on the fly, so I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Solution with Pattern/matcher won´t work if for example a keyword contains round brackets. Invalid regex error

Answer (score 7):

```
 String test='There are two dogs and a cat';
 set<string> a=new Set<string>{'dog','cat','pat'};
 boolean check=false;

List<String> lsttest=test.split(' ');

 for(String s: lsttest){
    if(a.contains(s)){
    check=true;
           break;
        }
    }

 system.debug('check...'+check);
```

You can use the above also to find whether string contains any word

Answer (score 0):

The following code works pretty well without any loop :

```
Set<String> keyWords = new Set<String>{'dog','cat','pat'};
if(JSON.serialize(keyWords).contains('dog'))
{
    System.debug('It contains dog!');
}
```

Comment: It is completely unnecessary to serialize the set before calling `contains`, as it is a `Set` instance method. Besides, this doesn't answer OP's question, as you are comparing to a single string only, whereas he wants to find words of that string in the set.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad sorry